# Using Regex to find String in Powershell Output

Tags: regex, powershell, appv

I'm using this command on Powershell

```
Get-AppvClientPackage -Name $UserInput*
```

which gives me the following output on the console

```
PackageId            : 6f02c6ed-0bd6-4df7-997c-73b5966d7a58
VersionId            : d6312052-0d90-4214-995b-da0461ace493
Name                 : FastStone Image Viewer 5.5
Version              : 0.0.0.1
```

I'm trying to use Select-String to put the PackageId into a variable, similar to this

```
$PackageGUID = Select-String ....
```

Is that even possible with a console-output? If so, what would the RegEx have to look like to find the GUID?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the `select-object` cmdlet or its alias `select` you can get specific properties...

I cant test it, but something like this should work

`$a = Get-AppvClientPackage -Name $UserInput* | select -expand PackageId`

Comment: @{PackageId=4a24e314-dcc0-4765-9472-0d019cd7496a}

Comment: Write-Host $PackageGUID gives me

Comment: So sorry, it's really confusing that pressing Enter sends the comment.
Write-Host $PackageGUID gives me
    @{PackageId=4a24e314-dcc0-4765-9472-0d019cd7496a}
as output.

Comment: if you only want `4a24e314-dcc0-4765-9472-0d019cd7496a` as output, you can use the `-expand` switch: `$a = Get-AppvClientPackage -Name $UserInput* | select -expand PackageId`